# Find the customers who have had more than one order in the same day with different addresses

Tags: sql

So I have fields of Customer #, Order #, Order Date, and Shipping Address all in the same table.

What I need to know is the Customer # and Order #'s from the customer's that have made more than one order in a single day that have different shipping addresses in their orders.

This is in SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please update your question with your query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain what results you're getting vs what you expect to get.

Comment: And tag with the database you are using.